# grep file from file

Tags: files, grep

What is the fastest way to `grep -v` a file against another one, both **line by line**.

does `grep` support this ? Or should I use it on two for loops ?

Comment: What do you mean "a file against another one"?

Comment: Yes: lines in file A against lines in file B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean use one of the files as a set of patterns for `grep`. If this is the case, you seem to be looking for a way to print all lines in one file not found in the other and this is what you want:

```
grep -vFf file_with_patterns other_file
```

**Explanation**

- `-F` means interpret the pattern(s) literally, giving no special meaning to regex metacharacters (like `*` and `+`, for example)
- `-f` means read regex patterns from the file named as argument (`file_with_patterns` in this case).